# How to detect cursor is on which Tableviewcell of tableview

Tags: uitableview

i have custom tableviewcell which has a textfield inside for user input text, now how can i find cursor is in which cell?

tableview willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath and tableview willSelectRowAtIndexPath does not return the correct index.

in editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath i want to retun UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete just for cell that cursor is inside. how can i do that??

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(self.uiTableView.editing)
    {

        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;

    }
    else
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

So thanks inadvance

Answer (score 0):

in the customecell, put id that carry the index , and in creation of table when create the cell set this id with the value

http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/

Comment: so thanks, i do this but in editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath i want to retun UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete just for cell that cursor is inside. how can i do that?? thanks